# Auth not working in Laravel Tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, tinker

From within Tinker I am trying to:

```
>>> Auth::loginUsingId(12);
=> false
>>> Auth::user();
=> null
>>> Auth::attempt(['email' => 'my@email.com']);
=> false
```

I am guessing that since Auth typically uses session data, and maybe sessions don't work with tinker.

Is it possible to authenticate within tinker?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's possible to login in Tinker. For example:

```
auth()->loginUsingId(1)
auth()->id()
```

Normally, the output of the `auth()->id()` will be `1`.

If it doesn't work for you, make sure the `storage` directory is writable:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage
```

You're also doing it wrong when you're using the `attempt()` method. The correct syntax is:

```
attempt(['email' => 'my@email.com', 'password' => 'secret'])
```

Comment: These are all good points.  In fact this led me to find the answer.  I have a custom UserProvider.  I implemented retrieveById using the email as the identifier.  I needed to call `Auth::loginUsingId('my@email.com');`

Comment: `Auth::loginUsingId` is not working on Laravel 6+,  but `Auth::attempt(['email', 'password' ])` is working fine.

Comment: `Auth::loginUsingId()` works for me in Laravel 8

Comment: @Pranta Saha *Auth::loginUsingId(1)* works for me in Laravel 7. It should have worked in Laravel 6 as well. Maybe you left out parenthesis after the 'loginUsingId' portion or left out a value inside of them?